# When I load 2.7GB RDS file in R Server, it occupies a space of 27GB. Why is this happening?

Tags: r, data.table

I have been using SAS for the past few years, and have recently started using R. I have this dataset(not that huge by SAS standards) which whenever i try to load in R, it occupies almost 10times the size. 
I use the following code:

```
assign('rawdf',readRDS(paste0("/srv/data/.../data/als_raw.rds")))
rawdf<- data.table(rawdf)
```

This load takes approx 10 mins.

PFB some pics attached FYR.

[Thats the size of the RDS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM0Hn.png)

[And this is the memory occupied when i load it as datafram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTM5S.png)

So u can very well see that the 2.7GB dataset ends up using 27.8 GB of RAM! 
Before you suggest that I convert it to data.table and then use it, i have tried that as well. I used

```
setdt(rawdf)  #as it uses referencing
```

and

```
rawdf <- data.table(rawdf)   #another way
```

But in both the cases the session gets hanged due to low memory! Any help would be highly appreciated. Not sure where am i going wrong here..

Comment: Do you get the same using data.frame? You should provide dimensions and classes of your dataset. Data size can be precisely calculated based on those, as there are no in-memory compression in R.

Answer (score 3):

RDS files use compression. Example:

```
> d = data.frame(a = sample(10,1000000,replace=TRUE))
> saveRDS(d,"d.rds")
> object.size(d)
4000672 bytes
> file.size("d.rds")
[1] 639072
> object.size(d)/file.size("d.rds")
6.26012718441741 bytes
```

Here I've created a data frame that uses 4000672 bytes in memory and saves to an RDS with 639072 bytes, a factor of 6.26 smaller.

`object.size` is a much better way of finding out how big an object is in memory than looking at how much RAM R has used with your system tools.

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely just the compressed vs. decompressed size.***

If you save a SAS dataset in compressed form then it's no different there, save for the fact that

(a) R is significantly more efficient in compression relative to sas7bdat (especially in the case of RDS files) and

(b) SAS can't use data entirely in memory (RAM) as is the default in R for speed.

However, R also has the ability to use storage memory like SAS instead of RAM if you choose. There are multiple ways to do this, the most common being `ff`. Google and Stack Overflow have many examples of `ff` if you need that. There are also many other Big Data strategies you can employ, like sampling, chunking, etc.

Incidentally, using `assign` like that is not a good practice, though it's unrelated to your main question. Better to use `rawdf <-`. Avoids environment and scoping issues. Also, the `paste0` was unnecessary.

***  unless that screen shot indicates your session has been running over 12 hours, in which case *for the love of R shut it down* and reopen a new session.

Comment: this is great. Also, about the assign statement, i will keep this in mind from now on. thanks!